# delete multiple enteries from table

Tags: php

**showall.php** first fetch all the values from database and **arrayToHtmlTable function** make them into table , I have added individual 
 delete and update button for each rows but I want to add checkbox box to delete multiple enteries but not able to figure out how to complete it

```
include "arrayToTable.php";
$bd=new sbs();
$sd=new arrayToTable();
$insert=false;
$bd->setDB(luDigi_db::factory());
if(isset($_GET['info'])) {
    if($_GET['info']=="coupon") {
            $r=$bd->execute("create_coupon","*","");
            $page="coupon";
    if(count($r)==0){
            echo "there is no data ";
    } else {
            echo '<input type="submit" name="delete"  value="delete" >';
            print_r($sd->arrayToHtmlTable($r,$page));
            }
    }





 function arrayToHtmlTable($arr,$page) {
       if ($arr > 0) {
        foreach($arr[0] as $t=>$v)
            $colnams[] = $t;
       }
        $r = '';
        $r .=' <table cellpadding="10" border="1" style="width:550px;"><tr>';
        for ($i=0; $i<count($colnams); $i++)  {
            $r .= "<td>$colnams[$i]</td>";
        }     
            $r .= '<td>DELETE</td>';
            $r .=   '<td>UPDATE</td>';
            $r .=   '</tr>';
        for ($i=0; $i<count($arr) ; $i++)  {
            $r .='<tr>';
        for ($ii=0; $ii < count($colnams); $ii++)  {
            $e= serialize($arr[$i][$colnams[$ii]]);
            $j=unserialize($e);
            $r .=   "<td>$j</td>";
        }
            $r .= '<td><form action="del.php" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="del" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$page.'"> 
            <input type="submit" value="DELETE" >
            </form></td>';
            $r .=   '<td><form action="update.php" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="upd" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$page.'"> 
            <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" >
            </form></td>';
        if($page=="coupon") {
            $r.= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="led[]" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'"></td>';
        }
            $r .="</tr>";
        }     
        $r .=   '</table>';
            return $r;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two checkboxes to each of your table rows

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'">
<input type="checkbox" name="update" value="'.$arr[$i]['id'].'">
```

When the form is submitted, you will have two arrays $_POST['delete'] and $_POST['update'] which holdt the IDs to be deleted/update. Then all you have to do is iterate through these arrays to construct your DELETE and UPDATE queries. Or if you are using prepared statements, construct two queries and execute them for each ID.